# Why selectrow_array does not work with null values in where clause

Tags: perl, dbi

I am trying to fetch the count from SQL server database and it gives 0 for fields with null values. Below is what I am using.

```
 my $sql = q{SELECT count(*) from customer where first_name = ? and last_name = ?};
my @bind_values = ($first_name, $last_name);
my $count = $dbh->selectrow_array($sql, undef, @bind_values);
```

This returns 0 if either value is null in the database. I know prepare automatically makes it `is null` if the passed parameter is undef, but I don't know why it's not working.

So here is weird observation. When I type the  SQL with values in Toda for SQL server, it works :

```
SELECT count(*) from customer where first_name = 'bob' and last_name is null
```

but when I try the same query and pass values in the parameter for the first_name = bob and the last_name {null} . it does not work.

```
SELECT count(*) from customer where first_name = ? and last_name = ?
```

Comment: Switch on Debugging and look if you are right

Comment: Yeah I tried debugging but when I go inside DBI prepare function it takes forever and eclipse stops responding.

Comment: "I know prepare automatically makes it `is null`" - no, it doesn't.

Comment: It doesnt work, because dbi do not use is null, it uses last_name= null i guess

Comment: use [DBI_TRACE](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.636/DBI.pm#trace) and you should see the SQL which is created

Answer (score 3):

For NULL in the WHERE clause you simply need a different query. I write them below each other, so you can spot the difference:

```
...("select * from test where col2 = ?", undef, 1);
...("select * from test where col2 is ?", undef, undef);
...("select * from test where col2 is ?", undef, 1);
...("select * from test where col2 = ?", undef, undef);
```

The first two commands work, stick to those. The third is a syntax error, the fourth is what you tried and which indeed does not return anything.

The DBI manpage has a section of NULL values that talks about this case a bit more.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, I have to create a where clause separately.

Answer (score 0):

So, here it is what I did. I added `or field is null` statement with each field if the value is  undef.

```
my $sql = q{SELECT count(*) from customer where (first_name = ? or (first_name is null and ? = 1))  and (last_name = ? or (last_name is null and ? = 1))};
my @bind_values = ($first_name, defined($first_name)?0:1, $last_name, defined($last_name)?0:1);
my $count = $dbh->selectrow_array($sql, undef, @bind_values);
```

If anyone has better solution please post it.